# Jquery add row dele buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the insertion button in the following code directory

How can I add a button to the insert section.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#row_add_btn').click(AddRows)
  
  var number = 1;
  function AddRows() {
    number++;
    if (number < 21) {
      var AddToRows = '<p><input name="icerik' + number + '"/> <input name="icerik' + number + '" /><input type="button" class="ibtnDel"></p>'

      $('#list_add_rows').append(AddToRows)
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list_add_rows">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="icerik1" />
    <input type="text" name="icerik1" />
  </p>
</div>
<a id="row_add_btn">Add</a>
```

Comment: I don't understand. You have a button which adds a new row. What are you wanting to do?

Comment: you have already your add boutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you planning to insert deletion of the the rows then you need to use the code what Will P. suggested above but in addition you will need to handle the maximum number of rows differently.

Increment the number in `if` condition and decrement on remove row.

Example Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#row_add_btn').click(AddRows);
  $(document).on('click', '.ibtnDel', removeRow);
  var number = 1;

  function AddRows() {
    if (number <= 21) {
      number++;
      var AddToRows = '<p><input name="icerik' + number + '"/> <input name="icerik' + number + '" /><input type="button" class="ibtnDel"></p>'

      $('#list_add_rows').append(AddToRows)
    }
  }

  function removeRow() {
    number--;
    $(this).parent().remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list_add_rows">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="icerik1" />
    <input type="text" name="icerik1" />
  </p>
</div>
<a id="row_add_btn">Add</a>
```

Comment: @ZaferBaşpınar : no worries, :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button click to remove the row, this jQuery should do the trick:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ibtnDel", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[jQuery on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)